# How to correct "time machine config disappears"

Tags: backup, time-machine, ventura

Macbook pro intel, macos ventura 13.4.1

I have 2 timemachine backups. A time capsule at work, an USB HDD at home. It's been working like a charm for years.

Here is the description as given by the command `tmutil destinationInfo` run in terminal app:

```
> ==================================================
Name          : For those about to rock
Kind          : Network
URL           : afp://My%20Name;AUTH=SRP@tc14._afpovertcp._tcp.local./For%20those%20about%20to%20rock
ID            : B64ECEE2-8E01-47A0-BF34-0F49EF4B2E86
====================================================
Name          : fry
Kind          : Local
ID            : 11FC6381-A756-4147-84FB-C82BFA2A5EC1
```

For apparently no reason, the timemachine setup disappears at some random time. No backup can be made... I'm currently at home, last backup was today at 15:41 on disk "fry", and it is now 16:55, the config disappeared. `tmutil destinationInfo` gives this result:

```
tmutil: No destinations configured.
```

Yet, the local disk "fry" is mounted, I can see the timemachine icon of the disk on the desktop and I can open it, browse it, etc... But sadly timemachine won't use it as the config disappeared. If I try to add the drive again as a timemachine disk, macos says "OK", but TM won't save. If I try to "save now", there is a count down. At the end of the count down, nothing happens.

The only solution I have found so far is to reboot. After a reboot, the tm destinations are back, until something happens that wipes the config off again.

I tried to reinstall macos, but this did not change anything.

What can I do to fix that ?